# What are the Newton's third law pairs in this diagram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

In the diagram below, block $C$ accelerates downwards when released. I'm having some trouble identifying the third law (action $-$ reaction) force pairs in my free-body diagrams. Please provide any insights to determining the force pairs.

[image: illustraion]

Comment: This is a homework-like question. Is there something you have tried in answering this question or a specific place you are stuck?

Comment: In line with the comment by `@LukePritchett`, what are you **particularly** confused about? Are you confused about all the third-law pairs in the situation or a particular one? In either case, what do you think is confusing you, i.e., what are the conflicting modes of thinking that you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

1. **B and A - apply force on each other using friction (because they are sliding one over the other).**

While it seems that B and C apply force on each other using the rope they are not count as third law because the force do not apply directly on each other - block C apply force on the rope (and vice versa so the rope and block C count as a third law pair) and then the rope apply force on block B (and vice versa so the rope and block  B count as a third law pair) .

The only remaining pair, A and C do not have any direct interaction between them and they are not applying any force on each other.

Comment: is 1 supposed to read "B and C"?

Comment: Of course. I suppose I need some sleep

Comment: The tension forces on B and C do not count as a third-law pair. They cannot be because they do not point in opposite directions. The rule that a rope exerts a force of equal magnitude on both ends is a separate rule from Newton's 3rd Law.

Comment: The $B$-rope and $C$-rope object pairs also apply third law force pairs on each other. For instance, if the rope has a high mass or the pulley has an appreciable mass or coefficient of friction, the magnitudes of forces between the $B$-rope and $C$-rope pairs of objects would be unequal.

Comment: @kb314 please note that I did mentioned those pair in my answer.

Comment: @ziv, I agreed. The comment I made emphasizes that those are in fact valid force pairs in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that your pair is valid by reversing the words, e.g "A pulls on the rope" (the rope attached to A...) and "the rope pulls on A".  The pair should be forces of equal magnitude of opposite direction.  The pair of forces always act on different objects.

So zivs answer seems correct but you could add the above, and also add this:

"The earth pulls (down) on mass C" and "mass C pulls (up) on the earth", both are due to gravity.